# Secondary voltage controls polarity of primary voltage

Tags: voltage, motor-controller, inverting

I have a control signal and a supply voltage. Basically the control signal defines the polarity of the output voltage.

- when the control signal is positive, the output voltage is the same as the input voltage.
- when the control signal is negative, the output voltage is the inverted input voltage.
- when the control signal is zero for a short period of time, the output voltage keeps the last polarity.
- when the control signal is zero for 2 seconds or more, the output voltage is zero.

Current draw from supply to output is 1 amp max. Voltage +/-15V max.

Here is a diagram of the above definition:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this by only using discrete components or do I need to add a microcontroller to generate some control signals?

Comment: What is this for?

Comment: Motor control. Supply voltage controls speed, control signal direction. Unfortunately the two are separated and control signal needs to be bridged for 2sec in case of signal loss.